# Angular (Angular4) Dropdown Component @Input and ngOnInit issue

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I created a dropdown component that has some strange behavior that I do not understand. Multiple dropdown components share the same reference to the `[items]` `@Input()`. So when I add a caption, the caption adds to the same `[items]` array.

**I just now realized what the problem is but feel like I should still post.*

**DropdownComponent.ts**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'dropdown',
    templateUrl: './dropdown.component.html'
})
export class DropdownComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() items: DropdownItem[];
    @Input() caption: string;

    ngOnInit() {
        this.items.unshift(new DropdownItem(undefined, this.caption));
    }
}
```

**Other Component Html**

```
<dropdown [input]="players" [caption]="'Player One'"></dropdown>
<dropdown [input]="players" [caption]="'Player Two'"></dropdown>
```

**Resulting Dropdown List for both dropdowns**

```
0. Player Two (caption)
1. Player One (caption)
2. Alex
3. John
4. Steve
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, the `players` property is the same between both dropdown components. I was imagining a copy of `players` being passed into the component, which is wrong.

Two ways to fix this:

1. Make a copy of the array in `DropdownComponent`
2. Always create copies of arrays in the component using `DropdownComponent`

**Solution 1**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'dropdown',
    templateUrl: './dropdown.component.html'
})
export class DropdownComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() items: DropdownItem[];
    @Input() caption: string;

    ngOnInit() {
        this.items = this.items.slice();
        this.items.unshift(new DropdownItem(undefined, this.caption));
    }
}
```

**Solution 2**

```
<dropdown [input]="playersForPlayerOne" [caption]="'Player One'"></dropdown>
<dropdown [input]="playersForPlayerTwo" [caption]="'Player Two'"></dropdown>
```